# How to convert a structuring element to an binary image?

Tags: matlab

How can you convert a structuring element to an binary image in MATLAB? For example, say I need to convert a square structuring element

```
se = strel('square',7)
```

Kindly help me in this matter. I really need a method or algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the array given by chappjc's code *is* a binary image.

Try displaying it like that:

```
nh = se.getnhood();
p=padarray(nh, [10 10], 0, 'both'); % This pads the array with zeros
imshow(p);
```

Comment: your ideea is good but i don't really know how to implement it in the m.file, i think i'm writting the sintax wrong, little help please? lets say i start with a se=strel('disk',4) then what? because when i type in nh = se.getnhood(), matlab returns: ??? Access to an object's fields is only permitted within its methods.

Comment: @user2980122 What you just wrote works on my machine.  Then you have a binary image (matrix).  That's it! Just like in my answer...

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Show us your entire code.

Comment: well...i'm getting the same "error" message (??? Access to an object's fields is only permitted within its methods.) and it doesn't go any further. the worst part is that i need this done for a paper/project at school

Comment: clear;
se=strel('disk',4);
nh=se.getnhood();
p=padarray(nh, [10 10], 0, 'both');
imshow(p)

Comment: Works like a charm on my machine. Try commenting out to isolate which line generates the error.

Comment: nh=se.getnhood()   this one

Comment: Finally works, i would like to thank you both, have a great day guys, thank you again

Comment: No problem. Voting up the answers you liked is a way to acknowledge the help you received.

Comment: @Jigg He doesn't have vote up privileged yet (at 15 rep). Instead, he keeps switching the accept...

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`getnhood` method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/getnhood.html) of the `strel` class:

```
NH = se.getnhood()
```

Returns an array `NH` as defined by the `strel` `se`. **NOTE**: `NH` *is* a binary (logical) image (matrix). You can display it as is or you can pad it as suggested by Jigg.

For future reference, you can use tab command completion to see the available methods for a class (hit TAB after typing `se.`), or you can use `methods(se)` to get a full list of available methods.

Comment: first of all, thank you, i'm a newby in matlab and image processing, please tell me how to transform all of that into a binary image

Comment: Can you kindly tel me how to transform all of that into a binary image?

Comment: The output of `getnhood` is a binary (logical) image, just small. You can display it with `image`, etc. but it is all ones for a square `strel` so it won't look like much.